# Why is the generic fiber of an elliptic fibration $X\to C$ an elliptic curve over $k(C)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let all varieties be over a number field $k$.

Let $\pi:X\to C$ be an elliptic surface in the sense of Schütt & Shioda, i.e., having a section $\sigma:C\to X$ and being relatively minimal.

I'm trying to understand formally how the generic fibre of $\pi$ can be seen as an elliptic curve over $k(C)$.

I was confused about this at first because a generic point presupposes a scheme, but all books and articles I've read about ellipitc surfaces refer to varieties, so I don't know what's going on.

Anyway, assuming we're dealing with schemes, let $\eta\in C$ be the generic point of $C$. In this case the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{C,\eta}$ of $C$ at $\eta$ is a field, so I suppose we can say $k(C)=\mathcal{O}_{C,\eta}$. But I still can't see how this allows me to see $\pi^{-1}(\eta)$ as an elliptic curve over $k(C)$.

Comment: Comment regarding the first point: There are of course classical varieties in the sense of algebraic sets etc., but one also uses the word variety for certain types of schemes. To give an example: For me a variety is a reduced separated scheme of finite type over a field. The definition of a variety varies a lot throughout the literature though, so that one really needs to be careful and check which definition the given author uses. The one I see the most is mine with the additional assumption of being integral, i.e. irreducible.

Comment: The point here is that whatever your definition of an elliptic surface is, it had better be equivalent to almost all fibers of $\pi$ being elliptic curves, which is equivalent to the fiber over the generic point being an elliptic curve. Remember, for most reasonable behaviors on nice schemes, "true at the generic point" is equivalent to "true on an open neighborhood of the generic point".

Comment: As a lazy addendum to @KReiser's answer below: take a look at Prop 3.8 of Silverman's Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recall the definition of an elliptic surface from Schuett & Schioda:

> An **elliptic surface** $S$ over $C$ is a smooth projective surface $S$ with an elliptic fibration over $C$, i.e. a surjective morphism $f:S\to C$ so that
>
> 1. almost all fibers are smooth curves of genus 1;
> 2. no fiber contains an exceptional curve of the first kind.

By generic smoothness for morphisms in characteristic zero, we have that there exists $C'$ open in $C$ so that $f^{-1}(C')\to C'$ is smooth, and in particular, flat. By invariance of the Hilbert polynomial for a flat family (see Hartshorne theorem III.9.9, for instance), we have that the arithmetic genus and dimension of the fibers of $S$ over $C'$ are constant. As the generic point of $C$ is contained in $C'$, this gives that $S_\eta$ is a smooth curve over $k(\eta)$ of genus one, so all that's left to do to show it's an elliptic curve is to find a $k(\eta)$-rational point. This is exactly what their additional assumption of the existence of a section $\pi:C\to S$ does by considering $\pi(\eta)$.

Comment: When you say $S_\eta$ is a curve over $k(\eta)$ you mean that the restriction $\pi\left|_{S_\eta}\right.:S_\eta\to \{\eta\}$ induces a field extension $k(\eta)\hookrightarrow k(S_\eta)$, right? And why is it true that $k(\eta)=k(C)$?

Comment: Is it because $k(\eta)=\mathcal{O}_{C,\eta}=k(C)$?

Comment: By the way, thanks for pointing out the existence of a section

Comment: 1st comment: That's not exactly how I'd put it (nor quite how I'd prefer to think about a curve - I like having a specific curve, not a birational equivalence class of them) but it's more or less correct. 2nd comment: yes.

Answer (score 1):

The word curve is being used in a relative sense to mean a variety/scheme which is one-dimensional over some field. Classically, a curve is one-dimensional over a "small" field such as $\mathbb C$, but the generic fiber is a curve defined over a "larger" field, the function field $k(C)$. Since this is itself one-dimensional over $k$, $k(S)$ is two-dimensional over $k$, but the word curve is being used to describe the extension $k(S)/k(C)$.

Another way to think about this might be: an elliptic curve is (the usual projective compactification of) a variety/scheme defined by $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, whether $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers, complex numbers, rational functions in many variables...

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't necessary, I've decided to post another answer to my own question, this time in my own words. I hope this can be helpful to someone as it was to me.

If $\eta$ is the generic point of $C$, then $k(\eta)=\mathcal{O}_{C,\eta}\simeq k(C)$. In particular $\eta\simeq\text{Spec }k(C)$.

Now if $E:=\pi^{-1}(\eta)$ is the generic fiber, we have a natural morphism
$$\pi|_E:E\to \eta=\text{Spec }k(C).$$

This makes $E$ a $k(C)$-scheme. Moreover, the section $\sigma:C\to X$ induces
$$\sigma|_\eta:\eta=\text{Spec }k(C)\to E$$

whose composition with $\pi|_E$ is the identity, which means $E$ has a $k(C)$-rational point.

Since the general fiber of $\pi:X\to C$ is a smooth, genus 1 curve, we conclude that $E$ is an elliptic curve over $k(C)$.

N.B.: I thank Tabes Bridges and KReiser, whose answers helped me to light the way.

Comment: You've left some stuff out here - an elliptic curve is a smooth genus 1 curve over a field $k$ with a specified $k$-rational point, which is a few more conditions than are in your answer here. (Separately, I don't really understand why you're posting this answer?)

Comment: @KReiser, I know this answer is essentially superfluous given the other two. I'm just trying to formulate an answer in my own words, and I hope this can be helpful to someone (it was to me, at least). As to what I left out: by assumption $\pi:X\to C$ is an elliptic fibration with a section, so the generic fiber is a smooth, genus 1 curve, right? I should probably add that the existence of a section implies that the generic curve has a $k(C)$-rational point before I conclude it is an elliptic curve. What do you say?

Comment: I've included this in the answer, I hope it's a little better now.